# How to handle missing 'emplace_range' in C++0x STL?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, move-semantics

I have two containers, let's say they're defined like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> a;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> b;
```

Assume both `a` and `b` are populated.  I want to insert the entire container `a`  to a particular location in `b`, using move-semantics so the `unique_ptr`s move to `b`.  Let's assume `i` is a valid iterator to somewhere in `b`.  The following doesn't work:

```
b.insert(i, a.begin(), a.end()); // error: tries to copy, not move, unique_ptrs
```

Is there another STL algorithm that can achieve this 'insert-range-by-moving'?  I guess I need a sort of `emplace_range`, but there isn't one in VS2010's STL. I don't want to write a loop that inserts one by one, since it would end up a nasty O(n^2) due to shifting up the entire contents of the vector every time it inserts. Any other options?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
auto a_begin = std::make_move_iterator(a.begin());
auto a_end = std::make_move_iterator(a.end());

b.insert(i, a_begin, a_end);
```

Comment: Awesomeness.  Did not know about `make_move_iterator`.

Comment: VS2010 does support this.  Good.

Answer (score 4):

You `insert` the required number of blank elements in the target (in one shot) and then use `swap_ranges`.  The source elements are going to be useless anyway since this is `unique_ptr`.

This *would* work for pre-C++0x, but the other answer is clearly better for Visual C++ 10.

Comment: It would, if there was a `unique_ptr` pre-C++0x ;) But it's a neat trick anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use good old `std::swap_ranges(...)`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap_ranges/